# Showing uniform density in $C(X\times Y, \mathbb R)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $X,Y$ be compact metric spaces. Let
> $$
> A = \left\{
>        \left. (x,y) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)g_i(y) \right|
>               f_i \in \mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R}),
>               g_i \in \mathcal{C}(Y,\mathbb{R}), 1 \le i \le n \right\}.
> $$
>
> 1. Show that $A$ is an algebra.
> 2. Show that $A$ is uniformly dense in $\mathcal{C}(X \times Y,\mathbb{R})$.

My thinking is we need to show conditions for Stone Theorem are satisfied. Then we rule out that the closure is equal to the latter. Therefore, A closure is equal to $\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R})$ and thus, is uniformly dense by definition.

To do this, we only need to show $A$ separates points, that is for all distinct $x_1, x_2 \in X$, there exists $f$ such that $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$. I'm struggling to do this rigorously.

Comment: To show that it separtes points, you should find two points in $X\times Y$ instead of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d_X$ and $d_Y$ be the metrics of the spaces $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Let $z_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $z_2=(x_2,y_2)$ be distinct points of $X\times Y$. Then either $x_1\ne x_2$ or $y_1\ne y_2$. Then points $z_1$ and $z_2$ are separated by a function $f\in A$, where for each $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ we have $f(x,y)=d_X(x,x_1)$, if $x_1\ne x_2$, and $f(x,y)=d_Y(y,y_1)$, otherwise.